# Unicode names of uploaded files will be removed

Tags: php, unicode, upload, filenames

I am uploading files with unicode names. after uploading i see a file with no name, actually unicode names of uploaded files will be removed. why? and how to solve that?

i am uploading using ftp (php) and there is no problem with Latin alphabet file names.

Thank you

Comment: Does your server filesystem support unicode names?

Comment: @MarkBaker, How can i define my server file system supports unicode names or not?

Comment: Telling us what operating system and filesystem type your're using might help us answer that

Comment: @MarkBaker, the OS is CentOS 5.8 , i will tell you the filesystem type soon.

Comment: @MarkBaker, They're asking me what you mean is what filesystem type we are using? . what have i say to them?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your filesystem doesn't support unicode names

You should consider stripping unicode letters or encoding them another way

A cheap hack could be to `urlencode()`

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the exact client and server implementations, the OSes they're running on and the way the OS is configured, etc...

For example a client might be linux using UTF-8 while the server running on Windows and is unlikely to handle a UTF-8 filenames, or the client might be Windows trying to convert the Unicode filename to some legacy encoding that can't handle it while the server is on Linux expecting UTF-8.

You're just going to have to learn the relevant factors or find somebody you can talk to in person, since troubleshooting it is likely to involve a lot of back and forth as you look at all the details of your case.

Comment: How can i define my server file system supports unicode names or not?

Comment: Pretty much any file system will support Unicode names. Windows' native file access API uses UTF-16 and NTFS actually stores that UTF-16 data, whereas most filesystems used on the various Unix platforms simply store an (almost) arbitrary byte sequence, whatever is passed into open(). Software using such a filesystem can be configured to store UTF-8 data (or anything else, you have to figure out how your system is configured). There are also weird hybrids like OS X on HFS+ where the native API is byte based but the disk stores UTF-16.